# CSRF field is missing when I embed my form with a requestAction in CakePHP 3

Tags: forms, cakephp, embed, csrf, contacts

I want to embed a contact form in multiple places on my website.

I developed a contact form in  a `contact()` function within my `MessagesController.php`:

```
// MessagesController.php
public function contact()
{
    $this->set('title', 'Contact');
    $message = $this->Messages->newEntity();
    ... // shortened for brevity
    $this->set(compact('message'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['message']);
}
```

I loaded the CSRF component in the `initialize()` function of the `AppController.php`:

```
// AppController.php
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Csrf');
    ... // shortened for brevity
}
```

The form is rendered with a `contact.ctp` and it works fine.

I followed CakePHP's cookbook which suggests using `requestAction()` within an element, then echoing the element where I want it:

```
// contact_form.ctp
<?php
    echo $this->requestAction(
        ['controller' => 'Messages', 'action' => 'contact']
    );
?>
```

And:

```
// home.ctp
<?= $this->element('contact_form'); ?>
```

The problem is that the form is rendered fine, but the CSRF hidden field is missing. It should be automatically added to the form since the CSRF component is called in the `AppController.php`.

I guess either using an element with a `requestAction()` isn't the solution for this particular case, or I am doing something wrong.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Request parameters need to be passed manually

`requestAction()` uses a new `\Cake\Network\Request` instance, and it doesn't pass the `_Token` and `_csrf` parameters to it, so that's why things break.

While you could pass them yourself via the `$extra` argument, like

```
$this->requestAction(
    ['controller' => 'Messages', 'action' => 'contact'],
    [
        '_Token' => $this->request->param('_Token'),
        '_csrf' => $this->request->param('_csrf')
    ]
);
```

### Use a cell instead

I would suggest using a cell instead, which is way more lightweight than requesting an action, also it operates in the current request and thus will work with the CSRF component out of the box.

You'd pretty much just need to copy your controller action code (as far as the code is concerned that you are showing), and add a `loadModel()` call to load the `Messages` table, something like

**src/View/Cell/ContactFormCell.php**

```
namespace App\View\Cell;

use Cake\View\Cell;

class ContactFormCell extends Cell
{
    public function display()
    {
        $this->loadModel('Messages');

        $this->set('title', 'Contact');
        $message = $this->Messages->newEntity();
        // ... shortened for brevity
        $this->set(compact('message'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['message']);
    }
}
```

Create the form in the corresponding cell template

**src/Template/Cell/ContactForm/display.ctp**

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create(
    /* ... */,
    // The URL needs to be set explicitly, as the form is being
    // created in the context of the current request
    ['url' => ['controller' => 'Messages', 'action' => 'contact']]
);
// ...
```

And then wherever you want to place the form, just use `<?= $this->cell('ContactForm') ?>`.

### See also

- **[API > \Cake\Routing\RequestActionTrait::requestAction()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Routing.RequestActionTrait.html#_requestAction)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Cells](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works like a charm.
I didn't know about cells, will definitely use them more in my CakePHP apps.